# Сокращённая запись if(class != null) class.method unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

как записать более кратко

```
GameObject go;

if(go!= null)
{

go.transform.position = vector3.Up;
go.Destroy;

}
```

Я знаю, есть сокращенная запись для такой проверки на нуль.

```
string name = value ?? string.Empty;
```

Но тут условие немного другое

Comment: а чем не устраивает это условие? а после условия еще код есть ? И какой смысл присваивать объекту позицию и сразу его уничтожать?

Comment: Никак. Кстати, ваш код не имеет смысла: вы объявляете ГО, и тут же проверяете, что он существует. И если он существует, как отметил Алексей, вы его куда-то перемещаете и тут же уничтожаете. Попробуйте привести настоящий код, может тогда что-то можно будет ответить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет в конкретно этом участке кода никакого смысла. Просто я подумал что в моем коде часто встречается участок 

`if(gameObject !=null) {Некое действие с gameObject}`

может есть более сокращённая запись этого 

вроде  `{некое действие с ??gameObject}`

Comment: @Dmitrii зависит от действий. Например если после блока кода ничего не идет, то можно писать `if(gameObject ==null) return;` тем самым вынеся блок кода из `if` разместив ниже и до туда будет приходить всегда только когда объект не null. Так что всё зависит..... Но обычно вроде так всё  и пишут...... Еще если куски кода в блоке `if` большие, то выносят в отдельные методы, например

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зря вы парня заминусили, народ.

В С#6 и вправду есть укороченный вариант проверки на нулл. Общие примеры:

```
int? length = customers?.Length; // null если customers является null   
Customer first = customers?[0];  // null если customers явряется null  
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();  // null если customers, первый customer, или Orders является null

A?.B?.C?[0] ?? E; 
A?.B?.C?[0] == E;
```

Источник: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

---

Думаю, что следующий код вполне должен сработать как замена твоему(не уверен т.к. не очень знаком с новым синтаксисом):

```
GameObject go;

go?.transform?.position = vector3.Up;
go?.Destroy();
```

Но я не уверен что unity поддерживает c# версии 6. Поэтому утверждать не могу. Протетируй сам. Но, скорее всего, юнити тебе скажет что С#6 не поддерживается. И в таком случае твой код и есть оптимальным.

Так же для использования даного синтаксиса нужно иметь VS 2015. 2013 не подойдет.

Comment: Про Null-conditional Operators понятно, что есть такой оператор. Однако если зависимых строк от условия много, то писать `go?.transform?.position = vector3.Up; go?.transform?.rotation = ....;
go?.Destroy(); и т.д.` полный бред и маразм. Проще один раз проверить на null как в вопросе...... Так что, в принципе, тот код, который приведен в вопросе не лечится через  Null-conditional и применяется не для сокращения подобных конструкций

Comment: ну в даном конкретном случае трансформ точно не будет наллом... Налом может быть только go. А значит можно обойтись и без того знака вопроса. Это я так, на всякий случай)) Тем более что не знаком близко с синтаксисом.

Comment: Проблема в том, что Unity не работает с C#6.... ответ, увы, но неверный. Но даже если бы работал (это возможно сделать), то вопрос был всё равно немного о другом.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, кто-то явно не читал ответ полностью. Последние 2 абзаца формально єто самое и говорят)

Answer (score 5):

Предыдущий ответ от **@Andrew** возможно имел бы смысл, если бы не два но:

1. Unity  **официально** не поддерживает ничего, что >= .NET 3. Разве что некоторые фишки из .NET 4. Поэтому возможностей *C#6* там просто **нет**. Отсюда следует, что и все эти `customers?.Length`, `go?.transform?.position` и прочие вензеля с null-propagation просто **работать не будут**.

Окей. Предположим мы, слава богам, воспользуемся библиотекой с *butbucket* для использования возможностей нового шарпа и сможем использовать новый оператор, **но(!!!)**, вопрос был в чём?

> как записать более кратко
>
> ```
> GameObject go;
> if(go!= null) {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Поэтому перемещаемся к следующему пункту:

2. *Unity* использует **[*custom equality operator*](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/)** (самописный крч) для  `Components` и `GameObjects`.

   > When a MonoBehaviour has fields, in the editor only, we do not set
   >    those fields to “real null”, but to a “fake null” object. Our custom
   >   == operator is able to check if something is one of these fake null objects, and behaves accordingly. While this is an exotic setup, it
   >   allows us to store information in the fake null object that gives you
   >   more contextual information when you invoke a method on it, or when
   >   you ask the object for a property. Without this trick, you would only
   >   get a NullReferenceException, a stack trace, but you would have no
   >   idea which GameObject had the MonoBehaviour that had the field that
   >   was null.

   Поэтому это нифига не сработает, если применять оператор относительно `Component` или `GameObject`. Прилетит только куча проблем. **[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544413/null-coalescing-operator-assignment-to-self)**  еще один пример и **[тут](https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/issues/4/null-propagation-and-unity-components)** еще один, из-за которого стоит избегать Null propagation при работе с *Unity*. Хотя бы с тем, что было написано выше.

---

Итак, подведем итог. Отвечая на вопрос: "Как записать более кратко `if(go!= null) {...`?"

Ответ: **Никак!**